# Which event when HERE map is fully rendered?

Tags: here-api

How to be notified when all graphics are fully rendered on HERE maps, for instance when huge amount of icons are to be displayed ?

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific? which API or SDK are you using and what kind of graphics or are you using the standard marker?

Comment: good point :(   javascript library, with non standard markers, built from svg icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly straightforward to check when the map is rendered - there is a "render" event (https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map-render-renderengine.html#h-map-render-renderengine__render-event) on the RenderEngine.
When target of the even is RenderEngine itself it means that the map was rendered. For example:

```js
map.getEngine().addEventListener('render', (evt) => {
  if (map.getEngine() === evt.target) {
    console.log('rendered');
  }
})
```

Comment: confused answer, render event as named should trigger each time we have re-render the map, but what's about the first time rendering.

Comment: the documentation for which events are available is quite horrible and all over the place!