# Detect when here map is done rendering

Tags: javascript, angular, here-api

There is an issue with detecting when the map has rendered the markers.

I have added a listener to the 'render' event:

```
mapEngine.addEventListener('render', onRenderChange)
```

and wait for the event to return the map engine to know when the rendering is done as I have seen as an answer for a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54078252/which-event-when-here-map-is-fully-rendered).

```
function onRenderChange(evt) {
    if (map.getEngine() === evt.target) {
        //render is done    
    }
}
```

The result is that the listener returns the map engine multiple times (about 40-45 times for the render of 200 markers and the number of times seems random with every refresh).

Furthermore, sometimes the map pauses the rendering for some time (1-2s) and then continues.
This happens when rendering changes in existing markers (such as change a marker's position).

What is an accurate way of knowing when the map is done rendering?

I use the HERE maps API for JavaScript v3.0 in an angular project.

The icon is a single global SVG icon reused for all the markers.
I have also tried with a PNG icon with the same results.

A group 'markersGroup' is added to the map when the map is initialized.
The markers are being added  to the map in bulk using:

```
    markersGroup.addObjects(markersToAdd);
```

where markersToAdd is an array of markers (H.map.Marker).

Comment: did u check this..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54078252/which-event-when-here-map-is-fully-rendered..?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned above, I have tried this exact solution and the event fires many times with the target being the RenderEngine itself. For 200 markers there are about 210-220 events fired and 40-45 of them have as target the RenderEngine. The numbers are different every time I refresh the page.

Comment: Any update here, did anyone solve this ? whether it is 3.1 or 3.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Map JavaScript API 3.0 is deprecated. I would recommend using 3.1.

Typically, the map is rendered one time while adding a grouped objects. The 40-45 times for the render of a group of 200 markers looks unusual. Not sure if it is caused by Angular. Could you try JavaScript API 3.1? if the issue remains, please share the snippet codes.

Comment: I have tried v3.1 and the renderChange events fires only 2 which is very good.
The problem with v3.1 and the main reason I don't use it is that it takes too long to render the markers on the map (almost double the time) and the map seems heavier.